# Custom Number Incrementing Field MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've had an idea for a html field in MVC. And thats the number incrementing textbox.

How would you go about doing that?

The idea is that I have form with some information that needs to be sumbitted. A lot of the textboxes are just number fields, so I would prefer to have them incremented with two buttons, the classic one that can be seen on VS in the toolbox for WinForms. Example: [HTML 5 Incrementer](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=FNMjqoV6ndV) however its not backwards compatible with older browsers. So I would like to make my own that is.

1) Create a custom HTML Helper which writes it out e.g.

`@Html.NumberIncrementorFor(x => x.FieldToBeIncremented)`

2) Find JQuery equivalent?

3) Combine both of those for the perfect solution?

Any advice and direction on this would be excellent! This is also a personal, self building project as well. So I would rather create my own then use a pre-made one. Want to expand my own skills. Obviously if this was for production I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. Just this time, I do :)

Comment: What is the context for this; what event would cause the number to increment. What is the original source of the number.

Comment: @PeterSmith I've aligned my question properly

Comment: is this what you searching for? [**NumericUpDown**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx) in Ajax Control toolkit

Comment: my question to that, is what has this got to do with Asynchronus Javascript XML ? surely its just a jquery thing.. I also use Razor not webforms.

Comment: was that for me? "Asynchronus Javascript XML"?... are you ok? do you know what the "Ajax Control Toolkit" is at least? the idea was you to look how they do it and do yourself if you want, at least you would have something to start, but if that's not what you want, sorry in trying to help!

Comment: no no, I understand you're helping, I was just asking for some clarification that is all.

Comment: what kind of clarification? read that page and what that toolkit is ... and keep in mind, that existed before jQuery ;)

Comment: I've read it. seems really good, and interesting. If you put that as an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to use the HTML 5 input with a type set to number.

To get this, you can annotate your model like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Integer)]
public int FieldToBeIncremented{ get; set; }
```

This will obviously only work in browsers which implement the input type number correctly, but you can use a polyfill to attach the wanted behavior on older browsers. 
Here you find a polyfill that does exactly this:

https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill